# Printing NV logo with Star SP700 (ESC-POS)

Tags: escpos

I'm Trying to print The logo stored in my printer.
\x1B\x1C\x70\x00\x1
this is the code i'm executing.

But I still cant see the logo when I print.
What am I missing?
im using c++ btw

Printer SP700 Star printer

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification, the 4th byte is a value in the range 0x01 to 0xFF instead of 0x00.
[Dot Impact Printer STAR Command Specifications Rev. 1.91](https://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/dot_star_cm_en.pdf)
Page 56, section 3-48

> ASCII ESC FS p n m
> Hexadecimal 1B 1C 70 n m

> n: Logo Specification
> n Function
> 1 to 255 Specified logo number

Answer (score 0):

this work for me : \x1B\x1C\x70\x01\x00

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).